# Mirror Transportation

Tags: everyday-life

Why do people transport mirrors in inclined position? I frequently find people carrying mirrors in slant position on mini trucks.I guess it has some advantage of carrying them without breaking,and I am now so curious to know the reason behind it

[image: Either sides of the wooden piece are aligned by mirrors]

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that it is just because it can be useful to sacrifice some horizontal space to gain some in the vertical direction, but maybe there's something more interesting behind it...

Comment: Do you have a picture?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus  I attached an image for reference.

Comment: Perhaps [this image](http://www.theglassrackingcompany.com/files/images/content/GlassTransport%20PS/Glass%20Trolley%20Trucks/Loading%20Glass%20Trolley%20truck%20with%20forklift.jpg) or others [here](http://www.theglassrackingcompany.com/aus_glass_racking/large_trucks_and_trailers/a-rack_transporters/aus_trolley_trucks) will do better?

Comment: Ease of loading/unloading probably; If it is placed parallel to road surface, the topmost piece and bottom-most piece are vertically separated meaning raising arms in awkward positions if you are manually loading/unloading-the person can walk keeping the glass at the same level. This is just a *guess*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The angle of inclination or lean of the glass should be 3° from the vertical on
static racks. For transportable racks, pallets and stillages, an angle of 5° – 6° is recommended. If the angle is increased above 6°, it will tend to put extra load
on the back sheets of the stack and may cause breakage."

Source: Glass and Glazing Federation, Code of Practice for Glass Handling and Storage. http://www.ggf.org.uk/assets/GGF%20Code%20of%20Practice%20for%20Glass%20Handling%20and%20Storage-4d4a73cca02f6.pdf

So basically, as far as I understand, it is a tradeoff between workers' safety (higher inclination reduces risk of accidents by falling glass) and stability of the glass (smaller inclination equals lower risk of breaking).